# Does WebRTC between two Android devices need a TURN server?

Tags: android, webrtc, simplewebrtc, webrtc-android, videocall

I am new to `WebRTC`. I understand that sometimes it is necessary to use a TURN server to make a video call between two clients in web browsers. For example, when the firewall comes into play. Do we also need TURN server in a video call between two Android devices?

Comment: I'm pretty shure you aren't understanding this topic... yes, ANY client need TURN server